# Join two unsorted files with POSIX?

Tags: io-redirection, sort, posix, join, process-substitution

Because the input to [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) must be sorted, often the command is called similarly to:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

This is not portable as it uses process substitution, which is not specified by POSIX.

`join` can also use the standard input by specifying `-` as one of the file arguments.  However, this only allows for sorting *one* of the files through a pipeline:

```
sort file1 | join - <(sort file2)
```

It seems there should be a simple way to accomplish sorting of both files and then joining the results using POSIX-specified features only.  Perhaps something using redirection to a third file descriptor, or perhaps it will require created a FIFO.  However, I'm having trouble visualizing it.

How can `join` be used POSIXly on unsorted files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with two named pipes (or of course you could use one named pipe and stdin):

```shell
mkfifo a b
sort file1 > a &
sort file2 > b &
join a b
```

Process substitution works essentially by setting up those fifos (using `/dev/fd/` instead of named pipes where available). For example, in bash:

```
$ echo join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
join /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
```

Note how bash has substituted the process with a file name, in `/dev/fd`. (Witout `/dev/fd/`, new enough versions of zsh, bash, and ksh93 will used named pipes.) It's left those open when invoking `join`, so when `join` opens those, it'll read from the two `sort`s. You can see them passed with some lsof-trickery:

```
$ sh -c 'lsof -a -d 0-999 -p $$; exit' <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
sh      1894 anthony    0u   CHR  136,5      0t0      8 /dev/pts/5
sh      1894 anthony    1u   CHR  136,5      0t0      8 /dev/pts/5
sh      1894 anthony    2u   CHR  136,5      0t0      8 /dev/pts/5
sh      1894 anthony   62r  FIFO   0,10      0t0 237085 pipe
sh      1894 anthony   63r  FIFO   0,10      0t0 237083 pipe
```

(The `exit` is to prevent a common optimization where the shell doesn't fork when there is only one command to run).